# retrive currency symbol on Android

Tags: android, kotlin

My problem is to retrieve the currency symbol.

```
val currency = Currency.getInstance("RON")
val symbol = currency.symbol //returns "RON"

val currency = Currency.getInstance(Locale("ro", "RO"))
val symbol = currency.symbol //returns "RON"
```

how can I receive the correct symbol?

Answer (score 0):

A work around. Or you can create a function with the following code

```
val locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales()

for (l in locales) {
    if (null == l.country || l.country.isEmpty()) continue
    val c = Currency.getInstance(l)
    if(c.symbol == "RON") {
        println("Result: ${c.getSymbol(l)}")
    }
}
```

**`Result: LEI`**

Comment: if I print:
${Currency.getInstance(Locale("ro", "RO")).getSymbol(Locale("ro", "RO"))}
I will only see: RON

Comment: I also noticed that. So I believe you can fix your problem by following this code